# How to downgrade previous version of Visual Studio 2019 professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am currently using MS [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Professional&rel=16) professional and the version is **16.10.0**. Found some bugs to build my project. The newly install and uninstalling process is tedious and time lengthy. Is there any short process to downgrade the previous version like **v16.9** without uninstalling it?

Comment: "Found some bugs to build my project" perhaps start by fixing those ...

Comment: @MitchWheat need also the version downgrade

Comment: You can install more than one version of Visual Studio side-by-side: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-versions-side-by-side?view=vs-2019

Comment: Also, if you post the bugs you're seeing we may be able to help you work around them more quickly than an install could complete.